# Validation upon initial entry

Tags: validation

I have a new SharePoint list in which the user enters an item number along with other information. Is it possible to check the item number for all other item numbers in the past 7 days. If it exists, prompt the user and then give a yes or no to confirm entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible. What you might use is JSLink to create some sort of a custom client-side validator. I, personally, found this link quite helpful when learning about JSLinks.

https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1-overview-url-tokens-and-applying-jslink-to-objects.html

EDIT: Also, a few great code samples:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am fairly proficient with most programming languages and environments but I haven't messed with SharePoint too much. Kind of got thrown into this situation of creating a bunch of stuff. We have a dev team that deals with it but they are updating to SharePoint 2013 and are unable to meet until the middle of March. I will give these suggestions a try. Thanks again!